# How to remove conflicting DNS server from systemd-resolve

Tags: networking, 18.04, dns, vpn

I've got an ovpn file which I am using to connect to a VPN at work.  However, when I am connected, DNS lookups on the remote LAN are sometimes failing.  Anecdotally, it seems that they fail more when there is a lot of traffic on my internet link.

When I run `systemd-resolve --status` I see two DNS servers, one is the IP address of the resolver on the remote LAN, and the second is 8.8.8.8.  I suspect that there is either some kind of race where it is querying both servers and when it sees a failure on 8.8.8.8 it just gives up, or it is somehow picking one or the other and when it picks 8.8.8.8 of course remote LAN host lookups fail.

If I run nslookup `<remote-lan-host>.<remote-lan-local>.net - <remote-lan-dns-ip>` the lookup always succeeds.  But without specifying the server it often fails.

I think I need to remove 8.8.8.8 from the list of DNS servers, but I do not know how to do that.  There is nothing in /etc/resolv.conf (it's showing the 127.0.0.53 nameserver), and there is nothing in my ovpn file.  How can I remove 8.8.8.8 or otherwise resolve the issue where remote LAN host names lookups are failing.

Per a request in the comments, the output of `dpkg -l *dnsmasq* | grep ii`:

```
ii  dnsmasq-base     2.79-1       amd64        Small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/TFTP server
```

And `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` has a single uncommented line:

```
[Resolve]
```

output of `systemd-resolve --status` WITHOUT VPN:

```
Global
      DNSSEC NTA: [several].in-addr.arpa
                  corp
                  d.f.ip6.arpa
                  home
                  internal
                  intranet
                  lan
                  local
                  private
                  test

Link 3 (wlp112s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: [3 local ISP IPv4 DNS servers and 2 IPv6 listed]
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

output of `systemd-resolve --status` WITH VPN:

```
      DNSSEC NTA: [several].in-addr.arpa
                  corp
                  d.f.ip6.arpa
                  home
                  internal
                  intranet
                  lan
                  local
                  private
                  test

Link 7 (tun0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: [IP address of remote LAN DNS server]
                      8.8.8.8
          DNS Domain: ~.
                      remote-lan-local.net

Link 3 (wlp112s0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
      MulticastDNS setting: no
       DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
```

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`/etc/netplan/*.yaml`:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager


$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 May  5 17:13 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
$ ls -l /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf 
-rw-r--r-- 1 systemd-resolve systemd-resolve 735 Sep 15 12:57 /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

`cat /etc/resolv.conf`

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search remote-lan-local.net
```

Here is the OVPN file with sensitive information redacted:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote vpn.example.com 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA256
key-direction 1
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<redacted>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
<redacted>
</cert>
<key>
<redacted>
</key>
<tls-auth>
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
<redacted>
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
```

Comment: Are you running dnsmasq*? `dpkg -l *dnsmasq* | grep ii` and edit that output into your question. Also show me `cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf`.

Comment: @heynnema updated

Comment: Edit your question again and show me `systemd-resolve --status` with and without VPN running. Also show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Is this a Desktop or Server installation?

Comment: And `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks, I have added this additional information.

Comment: Do you have DNS servers in your IPv4 tabs in your NM connection profiles?

Comment: @heynnema no. and i'm looking under the connection for the local WiFi as well as for the VPN.  I'm thinking the 8.8.8.8 is perhaps being assigned by the VPN DHCP somehow?  Because it doesn't show up when the VPN is off.

Comment: Take note of the current symlink for /etc/resolv.conf, and try changing it to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`. If that doesn't help, set it back to what it was before.

Comment: @heynnema `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` doesn't exist on my system. oh, and i just realized i didn't answer one of your questions earlier - this is a desktop install.

Comment: I'd contact your VPN provider.

Comment: @heynnema they have no idea. i'm apparently the only one at my office who has this problem...

Comment: Since we haven't been able to locate a file on your computer that defines 8.8.8.8, I'm at a loss. Sorry. You can show me the .ovpn file, with critical info redacted, and I'll take a look, if you like.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks, I have updated the question with this info.

Comment: Well, I certainly don't see anything suspect there. I'm out of ideas. Sorry. If you find a solution, I'd love to hear about it, ok?